# Redux toolkit returns the previous state when you make a request for data, how do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm in the process of making a feature to add articles to bookmarks. Now adding to bookmarks works fine, but I don't understand why redux toolkit returns previous state. When I click on the checkbox, I add an object with the article id to the bookmark array. Everything works fine in the redux toolkit, but when you try to check via console.log(), the new object doesn't appear there, but it will be there when another article is added. Each time it returns the previous value

It looks like this:

```
//Redux state
  
  [
    {
      id: 15
    },
    {
      id: 5
    },
    {
      id: 21
    },
    {
      id: 4
    },
    {
      id: 33
    },
    {
      id: 27
    },
    {
      id: 28
    },
    {
      id: 30
    },
    {
      id: 19
    }
  ]
```

```
//Getting the redux state in the console

[
    {
        "id": 15
    },
    {
        "id": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 21
    },
    {
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 33
    },
    {
        "id": 27
    },
    {
        "id": 28
    },
    {
        "id": 30
    }
]
```

Add to bookmarks code

```
//Slice

const initialState = {
  bookmarksData: [],
};

export const bookmarkSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'bookmark',
  
  initialState,
  
  reducers: {
    
  addBookmarks: (state, action) => {
      state.bookmarksData.push({
        id: action.payload.id,
      });
    }

  },
}); 


//Posts.jsx

  const bookmarksData = useSelector((state) => state.bookmark.bookmarksData);

  const savedBokmark = ({ id }) => {

    dispatch(addBookmarks({ id }));
    console.log(bookmarksData);

  };
```

Is there any way to get the current state, not the previous one? I want to send this data to the server, so that the user can save his bookmarks. I don't want to use redux thunk yet

Comment: I'm not a redux user, but if it's anything like other state management options I imagine it's asynchronous, and you are logging out the value before it has changed.

Comment: You misunderstood something there. I assume `savedBookmark` is triggered by an on click event or something similar. If that's the case, after dispatching your bookmark, you immediately log the `bookmarksData` which should return the old one before the dispatch, which is **expected**. After redux store gets updated, your component who consumes `useSelector` will be re-rendered, and that's when you'll see the new `bookmarksData`. In short, move your `console.log` outside the function, and you'll see what happens better.

Comment: it really works, but how do I send a request to the server if I can't write it in this function

Comment: @choz Thank you man I did the same mistake and yes its common for new programmers to make these silly mistakes :P BTW thanks again it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Redux issue. The behavior you're seeing is because the `savedBookmark` function is a "closure" that captured the value of the selected data *at the time that the React component rendered*.  When you `dispatch()`, the Redux store itself is immediately updated, but A) this component hasn't had a chance to re-render yet, and B) even when it re-renders this function instance will *always* point to the old data that existed at the time the function was created.

This is also true for *any* React component state update as well:

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const handleIncrementClick = () => {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
  console.log(counter); // still the old value!
}
```

This is a very common point of confusion.

*If* you need to get the newly updated Redux store state immediately after a dispatch, then yes, the right answer here is to do that in a thunk where you have access to `getState()`:

https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#accessing-state

Answer (score -1):

if you need to add side effects like interacting with a database to synonymously update both frontend and backend, try using redux saga or redux thunks.These help you handle asynchronous operations easily.
https://redux-saga.js.org/

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll have to use redux thunk after all, I don't see any other choice.